# Identify if row data appears multiple times in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel with multiple data. I have first name and last name columns. Now, I want to check if a person appears multiple times.

Example:

```
First Name    Last Name
Elle          Adobe
Mark          Zain
John          Doe
Elle          Adobe
Nathalie      Sparks
John          Doe
John          Viel
```

I want the output to be:

```
First Name    Last Name
Elle          Adobe
John          Doe
```

Is this possible? If yes, is it possible to add another column saying how many times they appear in the record?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following formula in `C2`:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(A2:A11, MATCH(0, COUNTIF(C1:$C$1, A2:A11)+IF(COUNTIF(A2:A11, A2:A11)>1, 0, 1), 0)), "")`

Since this is an Array Formula you'll need to confirm the cell using the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> keys. Just Enter or going to a different cell will render the formula useless.

Then, to count you can use something like this in `E2`:
`=IF(C2="","",COUNTIF(A:A,C2))`

See here a screen recording of me doing it:
[image]

Comment: Nice approach for a multi-column situation *(+1)*